# Simple Calculator Using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to build a very simple calculator that just takes the input from two text boxes, and adds the values together when you press the Add button and subtracts the two values when you press the subtract button. The total should output to a third text box. This is what I have so far:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
class Calculator extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      number1:"",
      number2:"",
      total: ""
    }
  }
handlenumber1 = (event) => {
  this.setState({number1:event.target.value})
}
handlenumber2 = (event) => {
  this.setState({number2:event.target.value})
}


exe = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({total: parseInt(this.state.number1) + parseInt(this.state.number2)})
}


  render(){
    return( 
    <div>
      <h1>Simple Calculator</h1>
      <form onSubmit={this.exe}>
      <div>
      Number 1: 
      <input type="text" value={this.state.number1} onChange={this.handlenumber1}/>
      </div>
      <div>
      Number 2: 
      <input type="text" value={this.state.number2} onChange={this.handlenumber2}/>
      </div>
      <div>
      <button type= "submit"> Add </button>
      </div>
      <div>
      <button type= "submit"> Subtract </button>
      </div>
      </form>
      <input type = "text" name = "name" value = {this.state.total}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default Calculator;
```

As of now, I am able to get the addition output to the textbox but I am confused on getting the subtraction output to the same textbox using a different button. I assume I would use something like `this.setState({total: parseInt(this.state.number1) - parseInt(this.state.number2)` but I am unsure of how to get it into the same textbox. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use a `this.state.result` (more meaningful than total) and `handleClick={this.handleAddition}` & `handleClick={this.handleSubstraction}` to your buttons and their respective method of operation.. Have a look at [this implementation on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-calculator-app?file=Components%2FCalculatorWrapper%2FCalculatorWrapper.jsx)

Comment: Can you make a small reproducible example using [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) ?